# How to prevent Tensorflow model from returning Nan values on prediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am training a numerical dataset for predicting a particular output and while my training dataset returns the prediction properly, when I import data from somewhere else to test the prediction, it returns Nan. Can someone help me out here?

Please find my code below:

```
early_stopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    min_delta=0.001, # minimium amount of change to count as an improvement
    patience=50, # how many epochs to wait before stopping
    restore_best_weights=True,
    monitor='mae',
)

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape = input_shape),
    layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(1),
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mae',
    metrics=['mae'],
)

X=np.asarray(X).astype(np.float32)
y=np.asarray(y).astype(np.float32)
fitModel = model.fit(
    X, y,
    epochs = 100,
    callbacks = [early_stopping],
    verbose=0
)

model.save('testKeras.h5')
loadModel = keras.models.load_model('testKeras.h5')

loadModel.predict(X[:2])
```

Output:

```
array([[52.616314],
       [51.21798 ]], dtype=float32)
```

Now I loaded a new dataset into the system to check the prediction results

```
testResult = pd.DataFrame(PostGresProduction(queryCheck), columns=['gender', 'age', 'mobile_number_count', 'mobile_registered_with_bureau',
                                                    'state_id', 'city_id', 'loan_period', 'repayment_period',
                                                    'moratorium_availed', 'is_married', 'is_spouse_working',
                                                    'no_of_children',
                                                    'is_joint_family', 'is_migrant', 'other_asset', 'is_political',
                                                    'is_police',
                                                    'is_lawyer', 'has_gst', 'industry_type', 'business_type',
                                                    'billing_mode',
                                                    'daily_sales', 'nature_of_invoicing', 'business_experience',
                                                    'online_banking', 'profit_margin', 'business_nature', 'taxpayer_type',
                                                    'filing_frequency', 'credit_bureau_score', 'loans_defaulted',
                                                    'loans_taken',
                                                    'loans_writtenoff', 'emi_left', 'min_repayment_amount'])
testResult = testResult.iloc[0]
testResult = pd.DataFrame([testResult])

testResult = np.asarray(testResult)
testResult.shape
```

Output: (1, 36)

```
loadModel.predict(testResult)
```

Output: `array([[nan]], dtype=float32)`

```
testResult
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.00e+00,  4.40e+01,  2.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  2.00e+00,  7.00e+00,
         3.00e+01,  7.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  1.00e+00,  1.00e+00,  4.00e+00,
         1.00e+00,  0.00e+00,       nan,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,
         1.00e+00,  4.40e+01,       nan,  1.23e+02,  5.70e+01,  2.88e+02,
              nan,  1.00e+00,  2.00e+01,  3.50e+01,  1.00e+00,  0.00e+00,
        -1.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  2.50e+04]],
      dtype=float32)
```

**EDIT:**

I tried removing the Null values in my dataset and it returned a value on predict. But that value is not right. It returns a four digit number while on the training dataset it rightly returns a two digit number.

Can someone help me here?

Output right now: `array([[2462.3406]], dtype=float32)`
Expected Outpute: ~`array([[30]], dtype=float32)`